# Como colocar fragmentos de código php en html5

Tags: php, html, html5

¿Cómo puedo escribir código PHP para que se vea en html?, se que existen los tags <html> y <p> pero quiero hacer un ejemplo de un código PHP en HTML. Es decir que al colocar el código PHP `<?php echo 'texto'; ?>` este no sea interpretado por el CGI.

Comment: esto es lo que necesitas?  <p><?php echo 'texto'; ?></p>

Comment: No, yo quiero que salga el texto php pero sin el tag <p></p> (no se si en realidad se puede)

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas son las etiquetas [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre) y [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code).

Comment: @Tegito123, el echo no funcionara, terminara escribiendo un parrafo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reemplaza
`<` por `&lt;`
y
`>` by `&gt;`

como dice alvaro, `<pre></pre>` tambien funciona